# Automatically run webdriver for e2e test in Gulp

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, gulp, protractor, e2e-testing

There is the following protractor.conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['e2e-tests/**/*.js'],
  seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
  seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar'
}
```

Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('e2e-testing', ['webdriver_standalone'], function() {
  gulp.src([]).pipe(protractor({ configFile: "protractor.conf.js" }))
    .on('error', function(e) { throw e })
});
```

This code works good, but I must execute `webdriver-manager start --standalone` before starting `e2e` task. How can I omit it? How can I do it automatically? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `seleniumAddress` config option in order to make Protractor instantiate a new server by itself when you start a test suite. Otherwise, if server address is specified, Protractor tries to connect to it rather then create a new one. Take a look at the section *Starting the Server from a Test Script* [in the docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/server-setup#standalone-selenium-server):

> Please note that if you set seleniumAddress, the settings for
>   seleniumServerJar, seleniumPort, seleniumArgs, sauceUser and sauceKey
>   will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we need to add the below in config.js

- seleniumServerJar: 'path of jar file',
- seleniumPort: `'4444'`,

and remove `seleniumAddress` from the config file.

It works absolutely fine